# What AC Adapter should I use to replace 2 AAA batteries on my razor?

Tags: batteries, ac, power-electronics, adapter, conversion

My **razor** works on batteries (**2 AAA batteries** to be exact, **1.2V and 600mAh** each).

The batteries after 3 years of quite a lot of shaving are almost completely dead, but I am used to this razor, can't say goodbye yet!

So, I know the procedure replacing the batteries with the adapter, but I'm not sure what AC Adapter I should look for. and preferably with **no soldering involved**. Any help?

***EDIT:*** *By **no soldering involved** I mean no use of capacitors, resistors, regulators etc.*

Comment: What kind of AAA batteries?  can you post a picture?  Is there a reason you aren't just replacing the batteries?

Comment: This is how the batteries look:
[link](http://prnt.sc/chpg5j)

The thing is that on the device manual, the manufacturer suggests that I should charge for 10 hours for it to work for 35~45 minutes straight before it goes off.
You see how this can be a little furstrating regarding that I always completely drain the batteries before recharging it. 
So I thought it would be easier to just replace the batteries with the adapter to take battery autonomy completely out of the way.

Comment: The picture shows AA batteries but your question says AAA batteries. If they're AA batteries, I'd recommend just replacing them with new, higher capacity batteries. You can easily double your run time.

Comment: A 2.5 VDC adapter will replace 2 x NimH. You probably want at least a 1A current capability and much more will not hurt. 3VDC is PROBABLY OK but MAY cause damage - probably not, but ... . || Larger capacity AA NimH will work as well. Best would be "low self discharge" NimH. Eneloop are extremely good. Some others are, some maybe not. Eneloop 1800 MAh (approx) will last at least 3 x as long between charges and if you leave the razor on charge occasionally if unused will probably serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

BEWARE that replacing independent internal batteries with a mains-connected power supply is a SIGNIFICANT AND POSSIBLY FATAL SHOCK HAZARD!  Quite apart (and in addition to) all the concerns about voltage and current and soldering, etc.

Are the batteries user-replacable (friction-fit into a battery compartment)?  Or are they hard-wired inside the shaver?  If they are hard-wired, a "solderless" solution would appear impossible.

We don't understand the part about "... always completely drain the batteries before recharging it".  WHY? How long does it take you to shave? Is it more than 35~45 minutes?  Is it not possible to just leave it charging overnight? Your description makes it sound like you are creating your own problem.

Comment: I completely drain the the batteries before recharging it to maximize battery life. The batteries are hard-wired inside the razor, but as I mentioned in the *EDIT*, by **no soldering involved** I meant no soldering regarding voltage regulators, resistors etc.

Comment: Clearly, your "draining the batteries" scheme is working to REDUCE rather than "maximize" the battery life. You are shooting yourself in the foot.  It will be difficult to find an external mains supply ("wall wart") that will exactly replace the batteries without some kind of additional circuit components (requiring soldering).   But MUCH MORE problematic is the EXTREME shock-hazard from making the shaver directly mains-powered.  I WOULD STRONGLY RECOMMEND AGAINST THIS SCHEME.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace batteries?  cut & solder

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/2PCS-BT-1011-800mAh-2-4V-Rechargeable-Ni-MH-Battery-for-Wireless-Telephone-/311660454016?hash=item4890692080:g:kEAAAOSwtnpXj2uF

[image]

or
these
http://www.ebay.ca/itm/4-Pcs-Ni-MH-AA-3000mAh-1-2V-Rechargeable-Batteries-Ultra-cell-Battery-Red-/231981108714?hash=item360326cdea:g:KrAAAOSwM4xXYnlL

[image]

**[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CEMZ2FE)** may not last as long as the batteries, but its 2.4Vdc
[image]

Comment: The problem with replacing the batteries with larger capacity ones is the charge circuit is (by the sound of it) a 0.1C charger. With larger capacity batteries that gets reduced. For 800mAh that then becomes 0.075C. For 3000mAh it drops right down to 0.02C and charging will take weeks - if it even finishes.

Comment: As I mentioned on a comment above, the battery autonomy is a problem. I prefer replacing the batteries with an AC Adapter (and use the razor instantly without "deadline") than replacing the batteries.

Comment: @Majenko that's exactly why I want to use an AC adapter than replacing the batteries with larger capacity ones.

Comment: @Majenko It will still get the same amount of charge in the same amount of time. I don't see how being able to hold more if allowed to charge for longer is going to be a problem. Likely he only uses his razor once a day, so this will likely at least double its run time.